Is there a way to have multiple styles and content in one ::before pseudo-element?
I have a div that has nothing inside it. This is a given due to the setup and can't be changed. I also can't add any jquery or javascript because it's a closed environment. So that leaves me using CSS and nothing else.
I am using psuedo elements to create a box/card to sit before the div.
I am using ::before psuedo element to the div to create a title. Also using the ::after psuedo element on the same div to create body copy.
However, I need to create a subtitle in a different font and font size below the title. Since I can't nest psuedo elements and I can't add any tags inside the content to target a string, I can't figure out if this is possible or not.
div::before {
    content: 'Title';
    background-color: #8fa63e;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    font-family: var(--head-font);
    font-weight: 300 !important;

div::after {
    content: 'Body text \A More body text';
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;


You can't add nested elements to a content property. You may emulate something by adding a svg data URL like so https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/BaeRQYM. See also "Is there a way to use SVG as content in a pseudo element ::before or ::after"

You could possibly use the ::first-line pseudo-element to style the heading and sub-heading separately. You may discover interactions or cross-browser compatibility issues which prevent you using this approach, but it might be worth a try.


div {
  color: blue;
  font-family: monospace;
}

div::first-line {
  color: red;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
}

div::before {
  content: 'heading \A subheading \A\A';
  white-space: pre;
}

div::after {
  content: 'body \A content \A here';
  white-space: pre;
  color: black;
  font-family: serif;
}
<div></div>




Ingenious! Works for me on Edge/Chrome and Firefox (WIndows10) and Safari (iPad IOS 16).

Brilliant! It does work!! However, realized that it doesn't work if the enclosing div is a flex container for some reason. Will work around that though. Thanks!

Also doesn't work if container div is a table.
